# Imported woocommerce variable products can't be added to cart

Tags: jquery, wordpress, csv, import, woocommerce

I have a weird bug with one of my customer's website. Website is working perfectly fine and all products can be added to cart when they are being entered manually (Product + Variations) from the wordpress dashboard. However, when I do changes through an csv file the changes are added to the database and prices are reflected on the website but the add to cart button no longer work.

- The csv file I use to edit the data is exported directly from wordpress and all the data (stock level, prices etc...) is good.
- I have disabled all plugins and the issue stays the same.

Comment: If you go to one of the newly generated products, and save it, does it become purchasable? Variable products run a `sync` function on save that might not get triggered on import.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I also tried going into a product and saving, it doesn't work.